# Define member functions once for two similar classes?

Tags: c++, class, templates, member-functions, class-template

Is it possible to avoid defining the same functions for structs **A, B** below twice? Their members are named exactly the same, but the **v0, v1 ... vN** members are of different type between the two structs **A** and **B**. If it helps the members **v*** are all derived from the same struct **V**.

Non-trivial functions (i.e. assignment =) can reuse a templated copy function outside the structs, like below, but it'd be preferred/cleaner if this was defined once and within the struct.

Is there a clean way to templatize **A** and **B** definition into a single one?

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void copy(T1& to, T2& from)
{
    to.v0 = from.v0;
    to.v1 = from.v1;
    to.type = from.type;
}

enum class E { TYPE_0, TYPE_1 };

struct B;

struct A 
{
    C0<float> v0;
    C1<int> v1;
    E type;

    A& operator = (const B& t)
    {
        copy(*this, t);
        return *this;
    } 
    
    string strType() { return string(type); }    
};

struct B
{
    D0<float> v0;
    D1<int> v1;
    E type;

    B& operator = (const A& t)
    {
        copy(*this, t);
        return *this;
    } 

    string strType() { return string(type); }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep a `common` base template class for the common functionalities and inherit from it for class `A` and `B`.

However, the copy assignment operator is a special member function, which I do not think one could template for different types return in the base class. Therefore you need to provide for each class.

Meaning, you can do

```
enum class E { TYPE_0, TYPE_1 };
struct B;

template<typename ClassA, typename ClassB> struct Common
{
   template<E type> 
   std::string strType() { return std::to_string(static_cast<int>(type)); }
   // need to cast the type to int before you convert std::to_string

   // other common-member-functions
};

struct A : public Common<A, B>
{
   C0 v0;
   C1 v1;
   E type;
   // ... A& operator = (const B& t)
   // bring the common functionalities to A
   using Common<A, B>::strType;
   // ... other member-functions
};

struct B : public Common<B, A>
{
   D0 v0;
   D1 v1;
   E type;
   // ... B& operator = (const A& t)
   // bring the common functionalities to A
   using Common<B, A>::strType;
   // ... other member-functions
};
```

---

However, both  structs `A`, `B`, seems to only differ from the two members (i.e. `C0`, `C1` and `D0`, `D1` respectively), combining both classes to one by making  a [class-template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), also an alternative:

Following is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

enum class E { TYPE_0, TYPE_1 };

template<typename T1,  typename T2>
struct AandB
{
   T1 v0;
   T2 v1;
   E type;
   AandB() : type{ E::TYPE_0 } {}
   AandB& operator= (const AandB& rhs) // one operator =
   {
      v0 = rhs.v0;
      v1 = rhs.v1;
      type = rhs.type;
      return *this;
   }

   std::string strType() const { return std::to_string(static_cast<int>(type)); }
};

int main()
{
   using C0 = std::vector<float>;
   using C1 = std::vector<int>;
   AandB<C0, C1> obj;
   std::cout << obj.strType() ; // Prints: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the use case for a pattern called CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern).

The idea is to define a base class template that takes the derived class as template parameter. Then you can safely cast the `this` in the base class to the derived class and access the derived class members in the base class.

This will also work for the copy assignment operator.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
struct CRTPBase {
    
    Derived& self() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
    const Derived& self() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this); }

    std::string strType() { return self().type;}

    template<class OtherDerived>
    Derived& operator=(const CRTPBase<OtherDerived>& other) {
        self().type = other.self().type;
        return self();
    }
};

struct A : public CRTPBase<A>
{
   using Base = CRTPBase<A>;
   std::string type = "A";

   using Base::operator=;
};

struct B :  public CRTPBase<B>
{
      using Base = CRTPBase<B>;
   std::string type = "B";

   using Base::operator=;
};

int main() {

    A a;
    B b;
    std::cout << a.strType() << std::endl; // Prints: A
    std::cout << b.strType() << std::endl; // Prints: B
    
    a = b;
    
    std::cout << a.strType() << std::endl; // Now prints: B
}
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hvdbWb).